# Is it realistic to analyze the bare components / ICs of circuit boards to understand how they work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

I am trying to learn as much as I possibly can about electronics by doing my own personal projects. I am wondering if you guys think it would be worth my time to analyze bare circuit boards and their integrated circuits / components so that I can get an understanding of how real electrical engineers have produced working products.

Example:

[image]

I am currently working on an electronic speed controller for a brushless DC motor. I have made [a simple prototype](http://electronoobs.com/images/Circuitos/tut_19/sch_3.png) that makes the motor spin, but it still doesn't work all that great and I'm at the point that I really have no idea how to improve it. I thought about buying [this electronic speed controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083FTHMQJ) and analyzing the circuit board and trying to improve upon my own design based on that new knowledge.

Do people actually try to understand bare circuit boards and how they work? Or does that sound crazy and nobody analyzes bare circuit boards? Maybe I should consider using a different strategy for learning?

Comment: In short: No. Trying to learn circuits from a circuit board that someone else built sitting in front of you is like trying to learn something from a book that's been encrypted. Real engineers learn in terms of circuit blocks. You should just be reading about each circuit block that makes up your motor driver (i.e. the half-bridge and its gate driver) and just reading whitepapers on brushless motor commutation/drivers.

Comment: Those 10k pullups on your prototype are going to make the gate switching way too slow. Get yourself a proper gate driver IC - then the rest will just be correct commutation.

Comment: You can't learn less from looking at **well-designed** boards. But that rules out a lot of stuff that's out there.

Comment: The problem with the example board: it's probably using either a microcontroller, or a proprietary chip that doesn't explain its inner workings very well (if you can find or read the datasheet at all). And the board may be multilayer, obscuring its layout details. There's always some way to drill down into things, but how much effort is worthwhile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Learning from circuit boards can be helpful if you have nothing else, its how many of us get started, but certainly not optimal. If you spent the same amount time/energy deciphering a textbook you would be much better off.

Regardless, the important part is the *schematic*, so if you can get your hands on that you're in business.

I would recommend looking for an open source motor driver, [O-drive](https://github.com/odriverobotics) comes to mind, but there might be others that suit you better. With these you can buy the board and inspect it, but they will also have the full schematics, PCB board files and firmware available (and a friendly community that can help you).

Something specific on motor drivers, they are often high voltage. This makes it hard to probe around with a scope since its easy to arc it accidentally (and out goes $200). Because of this, they sometimes are filled with potting compound and you have to scrape it out to get a good look. The one you linked looks fine, but just beware of that.

And, of course, there is lots of theory around this which you should learn if you're serious. I'm sure others have better ideas/specific resources on that.